# Website not loading css files on certain page

Tags: html, css, jekyll

The site i am building isn't loading any css/javascript file for certain pages. The pages in question are the markdown post files. I am using Jekyll to build the site.

Here is the link

http://joshhornby.co.uk/

As you can see the index page works but the blog posts dont.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `href` does not start with `/` nor is it absolute (`http://`) so it will use a path relative to the current page.

It is looking for CSS in the folder `http://joshhornby.co.uk/2012/11/14/`

Add `/` before your `stylesheet/` in the `href` and you should be good.

Comment: BINGO! Thank you. Spend hours looking and looking and sometimes its right infront of you.

Comment: firefox firebug is your friend.  Refer to the NET tab and look for red (indicating something didn't load).  Happy coding :)

Comment: One quick issue, now when i run the site on the local machine there are no style sheets now attached to that? I think im doing some very basic wrong but ive looked at the same code for too long now!

Comment: Starting with `/` goes back to the root domain.  For example `http://joshhornby.co.uk/`  If you're running on `localhost/SomeDirectory/` and you start with `/` then it'll try to resolve CSS at `localhost/` and not `/SomeDirectory/`.  Your blog engine should likely have a concept of `base url` that you can use and then use code (WP, PHP, ASP.NET, etc) to get a path relative to said base URL.  And if this is not an option, then look at the `base` HTML Tag (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) as an alternative (though not as nice imho).

Comment: So in other words its trying to find the files in my case on the desktop as this is where the file is stored (desktop/joshhornby..) I should set my base url to /joshuahorby

Comment: <base href="Josh/Desktop/joshuahornby" target="_blank"> i tried this and no luck :(

Comment: Im sorry for my slowness, fixed it.   <base href="http://www.joshhornby.co.uk" target="_blank">